# How is the wrong PHP file catching an exception?

Tags: php, apache

I don't know how the code from index.php is catching the exception when I go to temp.php in a browser. I could not duplicate this on a newly created local site (apache 2), so it may be something with my existing local site or the apache setup, or maybe I'm overlooking something simple.

temp.php:

```
<?php

try {
    throw new \Exception('temp exception message');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('temp catch die');
    error_log("[".date('Y-m-d H:i:s e')."] ".$e->getMessage(). "\n\n", 3, '/media/gcat/storage/it-all.com/Software/ProjectsSrc/Spaghettify/storage/logs/phpErrors.log');
}
die('temp end die');
```

index.php:

```
<?php
//declare(strict_types=1);
try {
    throw new \Exception('index exception message');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'catch index';
    error_log("[".date('Y-m-d H:i:s e')."] ".$e->getMessage(). "\n\n", 3, '/media/gcat/storage/it-all.com/Software/ProjectsSrc/Spaghettify/storage/logs/phpErrors.log');
}
die('index end die');
```

When I go to temp.php in a browser, the output is "temp catch die" but the error log shows "index exception message".

Answer (score 0):

[`die()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) is the same as [`exit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php). Both stop the script execution.

The call to [`error_log()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) in `temp.php` is never executed. The line you see in the log file is generated by the call to `error_log()` in `index.php` (when you load `index.php` in browser).

---

*If you don't load `index.php` in browser but the error line still appears in the log file, chances are that you have rewrite rules in `.htaccess` that route all the requests for non-existent paths to `index.php`. (Most PHP frameworks use such rules to handle SEO-friendly URLs). When you load `temp.php` in browser, the browser also requests `/favicon.ico`; Apache cannot find it and because of the rewrite rules it loads `index.php` instead.*

Comment: To clarify, if I don't die in temp.php I see both exceptions in the log. I don't load index.php in the browser. You may be right on the .htaccess - I will check that out, thanks!!

Comment: It was the favicon problem combined with .htaccess. Thanks again!